# Submit data and modify doc with AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know I can do the following with jQuery, but for the moment I do not want to touch it. So here goes...

I have a PHP file that generates an XML doc with all the data of a table if nothing is `get` to it:

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' );
$con = @mysql_connect ( "localhost", "root", "" ) or die ( "Couldn't connect to database" );
mysql_select_db ( "dw00154727" );

if ($_GET) {
    $ingredient = $_GET ["name"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO ingredient VALUES('$ingredient')";
    mysql_query ( $query, $con );

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ingredient WHERE name='$ingredient'";
    $result = mysql_query ( $query, $con );
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ingredient";
    $result = mysql_query ( $query, $con );
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
}

$doc = new DOMDocument ();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$root = $doc->createElement ( "ingredients" );

for($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i ++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
    $node = $doc->createElement ( "ingredient" );

    $name = $doc->createElement ( "name" );
    $name->appendChild ( $doc->createTextNode ( $row ["name"] ) );

    $node->appendChild ( $name );
    $root->appendChild ( $node );
}
$doc->appendChild ( $root );
mysql_close ( $con );
echo $doc->saveXML (); // parse the XML
?>
```

To submit data to it and modify the doc with it's response using JS I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var ingredient = "ingredient_xml.php?ingredient="
                + document.getElementsByName("name").value;

        xmlhttp.open("GET", ingredient, false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var x = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementByTagName("ingredient");
        name = x[0].getElementByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var tdname = document.createElement("td");

        tdname.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        row.appendChild(tdname);

        document.getElementsByName("ingredients").appendChild(row);
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type='submit' value="Add" onclick="submit();" />
</form>
```

This redirected the page from `ingredient/` to `ingredient/?name=Malt`, where `Malt` is the content of the text box when clicking submit.

Next, I modified the form and function with `FormData` example from MDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(form) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("post", form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.send(new FormData(form));

        var x = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementByTagName("ingredient");
        name = x[0].getElementByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var tdname = document.createElement("td");

        tdname.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        row.appendChild(tdname);

        document.getElementsByName("ingredients").appendChild(row);
    }
</script>
<form action='ingredient_xml.php' onsubmit='submit(this); return false;'>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type='submit' value="Add" />
</form>
```

This time it redirected the page to `ingredient/ingredient_xml.php?name=Malt`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onsubmit='return submit(this);'` and add `return false;` before ending function.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Same result. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `submit(this)` is called when you click "Add" so `return false;` is never called. You need to return false from function and call return from `onsubmit`:

```js
function otherSubmit(form) {
    /* ............ */
    alert('form submited');
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form action='ingredient_xml.php' onsubmit='return otherSubmit(this);'>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type='submit' value="Add" />
</form>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v3uouLjt/1/)

Edit: change to something else besides `submit`, like `otherSubmit()`

Edit 2:

You should really read more about [`XMLHttp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and wrap in functions, something like this:

```
var xmlhttp, table, xmlDoc;
function addIngredient(form) {  // XMLHttp function
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("post", form.action, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = OnStateChange; // use OnStateChange function to get response
    xmlhttp.send(new FormData(form)); // send form

    return false;
}
function OnStateChange(){ // from onreadystatechange check if readyState is 4 or 0
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 0 || xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        parseXMLResult(xmlhttp.responseXML); // send result to parse function
    }
}

function parseXMLResult(xmlDoc){ // parse your results
    table = document.getElementsByName("ingredients");

    // if table exists, clear contents
    if(table.length > 0){
        while (table[0].firstChild) {
            table[0].removeChild(table[0].firstChild);
        }
        table = table[0];
    // if table doesn't exist, create it
    } else {
        table = document.createElement("table");
        table.setAttribute('name', 'ingredients');
    }

    // create table head
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var thname = document.createElement('td');
    thname.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'));
    row.appendChild(thname);
    table.appendChild(row);

    // append results from XMLHttp response
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ingredient");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        row = document.createElement("tr");
        var tdname = document.createElement("td");

        tdname.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        row.appendChild(tdname);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);

}
```

You can see my example here: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2kLYwPNn) and [PHP](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jg1qyE1W) customized to your problem.

You need to use `onreadystatechange` to check the POST state and fetch response.

Best practice is to clear table and recreate with what you already have in your database.

Comment: I just did on the suggestion of your comment. Still redirects to the PHP file.

Comment: Change the function name .. something else besides `submit()`, check edit

Comment: Nope, still goes to PHP.

Comment: check your developer tools ... you must be doing something wrong ... any misplaced `getElementByTagName` or `getElementsByName` can lead to an error and submit your form.

Comment: I checked and found that `Elements` lacked the `s`. So it turns out I'm  still redirected to PHP file, but when I go back on the browser JS adds the entry to the table as expected. Problem is the redirect, which I, honest to God, have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: I can Pastebin the complete files if you wish to try them yourself.

Comment: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cr4mCdcn) and [PHP](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YFpJFV7T). Thank you for the help!

Comment: As I promised [HTML](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2kLYwPNn) and [PHP](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jg1qyE1W). Please read more on `XMLHttp` because you have a lot of issues. Look close on what I did there. Also please read more on `mysql_*` functions and why they are deprecated.

Comment: I admit I know little of `XMLHttp`, but I need to to use the deprecated function because the academic course apparently has trouble keeping up with the latest tech. *rolls eyes*

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but I think you should edit the JS functions into it.

Comment: Updated with explanation. Best regards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68262/discussion-between-oxwivi-and-mihai-iorga).